# Long files names

Tags: c#, windows

How to get the longest files names in a directory using C#?

Answer (score 13):

```
Directory.GetFiles(myPath)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
    .Take(howManyYouWant);
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(myPath)` if you want all files, not just directories

Comment: And if you're using .NET 4 then `EnumerateFiles` might be more efficient than `GetFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(<directorypathandname>);
var result = filelist.Where( f => f.Length == filelist.Max( f2 => f2.Length));
```

Now result will contain all files with the longest name. Usually only one I guess, but all of them if they have identical length, and is longest.